# Labelled Switch changing status after sliding it forcefully from righ to left

Tags: android

[image]

It is like basically when i am changing the status of switch from false to true it changes.
But when i slide or change it from right to left forecefully it changes its status which it should not.

Comment: So you don't want it to be **false** after it has been **true**

Comment: Once IT is marked present the value:true is stored in firebase so suppose if click on toggle button it should not change which is changing currently after i slide down the button from right to left forcefully.

Comment: Are you using kotlin or java?

Comment: Could you post your OnCheckedChangeListener ?

Comment: java...@Brijesh

Comment: @AnkitSharma Check my answer

Comment: boolean isPresent = holder.switchAttendance.isOn();
        holder.switchAttendance.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mStudentIdDeBoardMap.containsKey(id)) {
                checkIfStudentDeboarded(holder, id);

                return;
            } @Dima

Comment: private void checkIfStudentDeboarded(RosterStudentViewHolder holder, String id) {
        holder.switchAttendance.setEnabled(false);
        KZUtility.showToast(mContext, "Student already deboarded");
        notifyItemChanged(mIdPositionMap.get(id));

    }

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by making the toggleButton non-clickable after it's value has been true.

---

**In Kotlin**

```
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            toggleButton.isFocusable = false
            toggleButton.isClickable = false
        }
    }
```

---

**In Java**

```
   toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                toggleButton.setFocusable(false);
                toggleButton.setClickable(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the issue ?

Comment: Are you using switch or toggleButton?

Comment: I guess i mentioned wrong there..yes i am using switch

Comment: Can you please also add the code where you have used the switch

Comment: @AnkitSharma you are using onclickListener on switch and it's in the recycleview right?

Comment: @AnkitSharma The issue is with the Library that you have used. I tried every single option which are available in that. Only possible solution is remove this library and create a drawables for your switch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174254/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-brijesh-joshi).